# Find String in log files, and copy whole line into a new file

Tags: batch-file, replace, substring

Good Day All.

I have a bunch of log files that contains a certain folder in a folder path, that is "/input", that is part of a pathname that varies - "/input" being the only constant here...

How do you scan all the log files (*.log), look for all sub-string instances of "/input" and **write the whole line**, containing this part of the path, that is "/input", **to a new text file?**

Example of one line in a log file:

```
2014-01-16 00:33:57 10.0.1.169 ddca 192.168.34.11 21 CWD /DDAA/Input/ 250 0 0
```

How do I write all the lines, containing this part "/input" to a new text file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    set "source=c:\where\the\log\files\are"
    set "target=c:\output\folder\newFile.log"

    pushd "%source%"
    (for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /i /l /c:"/input/ " "*.log"') do (
        echo(%%b 
    )) > "%target%"
    popd
```

Search for the string using findstr. It will return a string containing the file name where the string was found, followed by a colon and the full line in the log file. Then, using `for` command this line is splitted using the colon as a delimiter and the right part of the line (the original line in log file) is echoed. The output of the `for` command is then redirected to the final file.

`pushd` and `popd` are used to ensure that references to the log files, and the names in the output of the `findstr` command, does not contain aditional colons that interfere in the splitting part.

Answer (score 1):

```
findstr /i /c:"/input" *.log >output.txt
```

The `/i` switch makes the search case insensitive. The `/c:` switch is used so that the leading `/` is not treated as a switch indicator.

Because a wildcard was used, it will prefix each line with the name of the file, followed by a colon, like in the following

```
filename.log:2014-01-16 00:33:57 10.0.1.169 ddca 192.168.34.11 21 CWD /DDAA/Input/ 250 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you dbenham. If it was that easy, why is your script not working? Did you test it?

Comment: @DextrousDave - Oops. Well, some times I can be a bit of an ass. Because of the leading `/` in the search string, the `/c:` option must be used. Answer has been edited.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works great. Why do you need the /c: option? To indicate the source drive the path is contained in?

Comment: @DextrousDave - I tried to explain that in both my comment and my edited answer. Without it, `"/input"` will be treated as an invalid set of FINDSTR switches instead of a search string.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options. You can create a small tool that does this for you, but my guess is somebody somewhere already done this. Did you google for something like this?

If you are up to some manual work, I know Notepad++ has the functionality to search through txt-files in folder(s) matching a (sub)string.

Also relevant:
https://superuser.com/questions/110350/how-to-use-notepad-to-find-files-in-a-directory-that-do-not-contain-string

Comment: Hi Sebastiaan. Thanks for your answer, but i do know of all the search functionalities in Notepad ++, but I am interested in a script that does that, since I would like to integrate that with something else.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure if you were specifically looking for a batch script or if other options were acceptable :-)